# Disable systemd service only if the package is installed

Tags: ansible

This is what I have

```
- name: disable os firewall - firewalld
  systemd:
    name: firewalld
    state: stopped
    enabled: no
```

This task works fine on hosts where `firewalld` package is installed but fails on hosts where it is not.

What is the best simple approach to make sure it can handle hosts which do not have `firewalld` installed? I do not want to use any CMDB as it's an additional setup. Also, I want the task to be *idempotent*; using a shell command like `dpkg` or `rpm` to query if `firewalld` is installed makes the ansible playbook summary report changes which I do not want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is an example using `failed_when:`.  While it does run every time, it ignores the failure if the package is not installed:

```
- name: Stop and disable chrony service
  service:
    name:    chronyd
    enabled: no
    state:   stopped
  register: chronyd_service_result
  failed_when: "chronyd_service_result is failed and 'Could not find the requested service' not in chronyd_service_result.msg"
```

Comment: This is particularly useful for security hardening scripts (eg. CIS hardening guidelines and company IT policy). Sometimes the guidelines call for the disabling of system processes that may not be present. Also, filters are deprecated so the 2019 edition of `chronyd_service_result|failed` is `chronyd_service_result is failed`

Answer (score 1):

> What is the best approach to make sure it can handle hosts which do not have `firewalld` installed?

Get the information on which systems `firewalld` is installed from a CMDB of any kind (like Ansible vars files, since you already use Ansible), and run the task on those systems.

Likewise, do not run the task on systems that do not have `firewalld` installed according to the configuration pulled from the CMDB.

---

The actual implementation vary. Among others: specifying appropriate host groups for plays, using conditional in the task, using limit option for inventory.

Comment: I do not have a CMDB setup and do not want to set one up. We have minimal systems and having a CMDB is a overkill.

Comment: That doesn't mean it's not the best way, which the question asks about. I'm also not sure how CMDB in the form of, for example, Ansible vars files can be an overkill.

Answer (score 0):

In your Ansible play. you can check first if the package is installed before trying to stop/start it.

something similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46975808/3768721

Comment: Yeah, I know about this. The problem is, running a shell command to query makes the playbook non-idempotent. At the end of the ansible run, it reports a change because or running the shell command.

Comment: You need to be more specific when you ask questions.

Answer (score 0):

With `shell` approach:

```yaml
- name: Disable {{ service }} if enabled
  shell: if systemctl is-enabled --quiet {{ service }}; then systemctl disable {{ service }} && echo disable_ok ; fi
  register: output
  changed_when: "'disable_ok' in output.stdout"
```

It produces 3 states:

- service is absent or disabled already — `ok`
- service exists and was disabled — `changed`
- service exists and disable failed — `failed`