# Ansible: disable service only if present

Tags: ansible

Is there any nice way to do disable and stop a service, but only if it's installed on server? Something like this:

```
- service: name={{ item }} enabled=no state=stopped only_if_present=yes
  with_items:
  - avahi-daemon
  - abrtd
  - abrt-ccpp
```

Note that "only_if_present" is a keyword that doesn't exist right now in Ansible, but I suppose my goal is obvious.

Comment: what you mean by only_if_present is the package is installed or if service is running?

Comment: The real question is, why are you trying to operate on a service that is not installed on the host?  Is it SUPPOSED to be installed?  Is it normally installed and you want to remove it from all the hosts?  If some hosts are supposed to have it and some are not, put them into different groups and operate only on the group that has it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable systemd service only if the package is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46968364/disable-systemd-service-only-if-the-package-is-installed)

Comment: @Jack answer to all your questions: "it doesn't matter". All I want is to disable this service, in case it's present on target host. Imagine I want to run this on 4000 servers with many different operating systems with many different versions, from CentOS5, RHEL7, to Debian and similar.

Comment: @sys0dm1n "only_if_present" should mean "only if such a service exists on host".

Comment: Well, @Petr, if you have 4000 servers and it doesn't matter to you what services are on which servers, I can only say, "Good luck with that."

Answer (score 6):

I don't know what is the package name in your case, but you can do something similar to this:

```
- shell: dpkg-query -W 'avahi'
  ignore_errors: True
  register: is_avahi
  when: ansible_distribution == 'Debian' or ansible_distribution == 'Ubuntu'

- shell: rpm -q 'avahi'
  ignore_errors: True
  register: is__avahi
  when: ansible_distribution == 'CentOS' or ansible_distribution == 'Red Hat Enterprise Linux'

- service: name=avahi-daemon enabled=no state=stopped
  when: is_avahi|failed
```

> Update: I have added conditions so that the playbook works when you have  multiple different distros, you might need to adapt it to fit your requirements.

Comment: well, this works, but only on debian-like systems. Our hosts range multiple different distros.

Answer (score 4):

Universal solution for systemd services:

```yaml
- name: Disable services if enabled
  shell: if systemctl is-enabled --quiet {{ item }}; then systemctl disable {{ item }} && echo disable_ok ; fi
  register: output
  changed_when: "'disable_ok' in output.stdout"
  loop:
    - avahi-daemon
    - abrtd
    - abrt-ccpp
```

It produces 3 states:

- service is absent or disabled already — `ok`
- service exists and was disabled — `changed`
- service exists and disable failed — `failed`